# How come look ups in hash tables are O(1)?

Tags: performance, time, big-o, hashtable

If I have a dictionary with n keys, for me the only way to verify if a certain key K is among those is by going through each one of the n keys and comparing. This, in my thinking, is O(n). What is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: You'd usually only check if that specific key corresponds to some value.